# Mail keeps crashing when clicking on gmail mailbox

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, crash, gmail

since yesterday afternoon my Mail.app keeps crashing when I am clicking on my gmail mailbox. I instantly see the beachball and looking into Activity Monitor it tells me that Mail.app uses 100% CPU while (Not Responding).

I tried restarting the Computer, I updated the System, I deleted all Mail-Containers from the Library Folder and also deleted the Envelope index files. None of this helped, still keeps happening.

Other Mailboxes on this system (iMac) work fine. The mailbox causing the problems works in Mail on my iPhone and my MacBook. Hence, I figured it has to have something to do with the iMac in combination with this particular mailbox.

I also checked and repaired file permissions using Disk Utility.

My System:

Hardware Overview:

```
  Model Name:   iMac
  Model Identifier: iMac14,2
  Processor Name:   Intel Core i7
  Processor Speed:  3,5 GHz
  Number of Processors: 1
  Total Number of Cores:    4
  L2 Cache (per Core):  256 KB
  L3 Cache: 8 MB
  Memory:   32 GB
  Boot ROM Version: IM142.0118.B11
  SMC Version (system): 2.15f7
```

The crash report (the beginning of it) when Force Quitting the unresponsive application:

```
Date/Time:       2015-07-07 13:35:31 +0200
OS Version:      10.10.4 (Build 14E46)
Architecture:    x86_64h
Report Version:  21

Command:         Mail
Path:            /Applications/Mail.app/Contents/MacOS/Mail
Version:         8.2 (2102)
Build Version:   1
Project Name:    Mail
Source Version:  2102000000000000
Parent:          launchd [1]
PID:             2101

Event:           hang
Duration:        1.00s (process was unresponsive for 263 seconds before sampling)
Steps:           11 (100ms sampling interval)

Hardware model:  iMac14,2
Active cpus:     8

Fan speed:       1199 rpm
```

I am really out of ideas what to do here. Would be happy for suggestions!

Thank you and kind regards

Nils

Comment: Have you tried deleting and recreating your Gmail account settings from System Preferences > Internet Accounts? Also, do you have Mail open automatically at Login?

Comment: I deactivated the account for this machine since deleting it would also delete it from all my other devices - or so the message stated. I will try that now nonetheless. I have not start mail automatically at login.

Comment: It might be helpful to see the rest of the crash report (it contains some details of what the various threads in the app were doing when you force quit it).

Comment: Have you received any other emails since? It is possible that there is an email which is causing Mail.app to crash on the preview pane. You can try to hide the pane while on another account or have another email come in which bounces the topmost one down

Comment: @Ashley Hm, weird. I don't get the option to see and report the crash to apple anymore.

Comment: @smooosher Yes, I received new mails since and they showed up in the account, however, when clicking on it it keeps crashing. Still works on my MBP and iPhone, so it has to be something with my iMac. :/

Comment: @NilsHaldenwang The reports should be visible in /Applications/Utilities/Console.app, I think under User Diagnostic Reports or System Diagnostic Reports.

Comment: Have you tried to move the last emails you received on your google account since before the crashing to a different folder on a working device/webmail? Might be a problem related to a certain email which when trying to render crashes the app.

Comment: Thx for the ideas guys. I have absolutely no idea why but it does not crash anymore since today.

Comment: @NilsHaldenwang If the issue is resolved, I recommend removing the bounty and updating your question to reflect that the issue is no longer occurring. This way you keep your reputation points and nobody spends time trying to resolve an issue that is already resolved :)